# How do I apply a script in Google Sheets to all but two specific tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script on a Google Sheet which applies a timestamp when any cell in every alternate column is edited. Currently this applies to all tabs. I would like it to apply to all EXCEPT two tabs which are named 'Tab1' and 'Tab2'. This is the script I am using:

```html
var startingRow = 3
var startingCol = 7

function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var colNum = range.getColumn();

  if ((row < startingRow) || (colNum < startingCol) || (colNum % 2 ==0)) {
    // Ignore
  }
  else
  {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var dateCell = sheet.getRange(row,colNum+1);
    dateCell.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run the script when the active sheet is not `Tab1` and `Tab2` in the active Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var colNum = range.getColumn();
```

#### To:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var colNum = range.getColumn();

  // I added below script
  const ignoreTabs = ["Tab1", "Tab2"];  // Please set the tab name you want to ignore.
  if (ignoreTabs.includes(range.getSheet().getSheetName())) return;
```

- In this modification, when the active sheet name is `Tab1` and `Tab2`, the script is finished by `return`.

#### References:

- [getSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet)
- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetName())
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Great, thank you - simple solution which works perfectly.

Comment: @Mark Anderson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.